# Change color of action bar shadow gradient

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-xml, android-theme

I'd like to change the color of the shadow gradient that appears at the bottom of the `Action Bar`.  I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`.

I've looked through the XML resources trying to determine where this shape is defined but I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked through the XML resources trying to determine where this
>   shape is defined

They are not defined as XML  shapes. The ActionBar/ABS uses 9Patches.

You can use the [ActionBar Style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). It will generate all the styles and 9Patches for you.

Comment: That's a handy tool, but the creation of the assets isn't my problem.  What do I do with them once I have them?

Comment: Set the generated theme as your application theme