# Set custom shadow to AppBarLayout or Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to set custom shadow to `Toolbar`. Currently is shown default shadow, but it not appropriate for me. So how can I set a custom shadow?

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102443/change-color-of-action-bar-shadow-gradient.    May help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it out. But this approach do not give the same shadow as `BottomNavigationView` has. This is a minor issue, but maybe you have suggestions?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/PageBackground">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_bar_shadow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_shadow.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#15000000"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat` to appbar and toolbar

`android:theme` for appbar

`android:popuptheme` for toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the `elevation` attribute after API 21 (Android Lollipop). Which is the easiest way now. Before however ,you can  add the shadow programmatically, for example using a custom view placed below the `Toolbar`.

```
@layout/toolbar

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
```

@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/> </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This not appropriate, because shadow is not transparent in this case, and you will see this issue while scrolling page

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe it's not the most efficient way, but it works for me.

Comment: I have improved your layout so please see my separate answer